# TestNG dependencies with group of groups

Tags: testng

I have a class containing two methods, which belong to two different groups:

```
package foo.bar;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Five {
    private int counter = 0;
    @Test(groups = {"group1"})
    public void testOne() {
        System.out.println("Counter value in group1:" + counter);
    }

    @Test(groups = {"group2"})
    public void testTwo() {
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Counter value in group2 :" + counter);
    }
}
```

I have created the `testng.xml` file to define dependencies between groups and run.

```
 <suite name="Sample 1">
    <test name="MySuite">
        <!-- filters testOne, but since it dependsOn non existent group it fails. -->
        <groups>
        <dependencies>
            <group name="group2" depends-on="group1"/>
        </dependencies>         
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="foo.bar.Five"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

It works. But when I define a new group and mark it as dependent of another it fails:

```
<suite name="Sample 1">
        <test name="MySuite">
            <groups>
                <define name="group3">
                    <include name="group2"/>
                </define>
                <dependencies>
                    <group name="group2" depends-on="group3"/>
                </dependencies>
            </groups>
            <classes>
                <class name="foo.bar.Five"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

In above, I created a new group i.e. group3, and marked group2 dependent on group3. But when I run, I get

```
DependencyMap::Method "Five.testTwo()[pri:0, instance:oracle.sysman.test.sample.Five@48ae10cd]" depends on nonexistent group "group3"
```

Comment: have you marked any testmethod to fall in group3?

Comment: No. As you can see group3 is nothing but created out of group1. And both my tests are passing (they just have system.out.println).

Answer (score 0):

> The exception is obvious.

The whole purpose of having group dependencies is to control the execution of `@Test` method(s) belonging to certain group(s), on the basis of execution status of other `@Test` method(s) belonging to certain other groups.

**Dependent** must have a **dependency**.

So here in your case at least 1 `@Test` method must exist in `group3` on which all methods belonging to `group2`can depend on. If no method exists in `group3` then how methods in `group2` can wait for non existing method to finish it's execution.

More:

```
<groups>
            <define name="group3">
                <include name="group2"/>
            </define>
...
```

Defining a group which includes another group does not mean that methods belongs to `group2` also belongs to `group3`. It's meaning is, execution of `group3` will also include methods of `group2`.